# Retrieve Docker application results before exiting

Tags: docker, containers

I need to run an external application using docker. I use the following code to run the application.

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/PSORTb,target=/home/tdi/PSORTb/ --rm -ti "brinkmanlab/psortb_commandline:1.0.2" /usr/local/psortb/bin/psort -i /home/tdi/PSORTb/all_validated_effectors.fasta --negative
```

I use `mount` to point towards my local input file and `--negative` is a flag used in the application. However, my question is how to retrieve the output. If I understand correctly, the docker container exits after the job is completed and simultaneously deletes the output file. After running the above code, I get the following message.

```
Saving results to /20210910084030_psortb_gramneg.txt
```

How can I read this file or save locally?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Docker Volume to persist the data to the Host.

Follow these steps:

#### Create a directory on the Host next to the Dockerfile, or where you start the docker command from

```sh
mkdir outputfiles
```

#### Write the output in the Application to a directory

Make sure your application is writing the outputfile to a certain directory. Let's say /output

#### Connect both directories with a 'Volume'

See the "-v" line below:

```sh
docker run 
    --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/PSORTb,target=/home/tdi/PSORTb/ 
    --rm 
    -v ./outputfiles:/output
    -ti "brinkmanlab/psortb_commandline:1.0.2" /usr/local/psortb/bin/psort 
    -i /home/tdi/PSORTb/all_validated_effectors.fasta 
    --negative
```

After the container get removed, the file will still be there.

[See these Docs for more info](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/05_persisting_data/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. By default, the results are stored in the root of the container, not in some directory. How can I change this without changing the source code of the application.

Comment: Well, that's not possible. Because mapping the volume will overwrite everything in the location in the container. Volume-mapping does not do a merge with data already there. That's why you need a separate container.

Answer (score 0):

Mount a host directory as a volume and write the file there instead of in the / of the container. Once the container exits, the files will remain inside the directory on the host.

In the example below, the host's "/root" directory is mapped to the "/opt/root" directory inside the container, which is a strange directory to map, but it should work just as almost any other dir. The container would write its files to "/opt/root" internally and then the host would retrieve them from "/root" externally once the work has completed.

The "-v" parameter is what you want to look at here:

> The following example mounts the host's /root directory into the
> Docker container at /opt/root:
> `docker run -t -i -v /root:/opt/root debian /bin/bash`

https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_Linux_Tutorial_Using_Docker_Containers_LTS_1/page/cdv1540580083374.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose the directory where the file is saved then you can probably use another **bind mount** to get the file saved in the host filesystem:

```sh
docker run -v "$(pwd)/output:/output/dir"
```

But if the file is saved in the container's root directory (`/`) I don't think this is the best solution.

Another way would be to keep the container after it stopped by removing the `--rm` option from your command.
Then you can copy the file from the container to the host filesystem using [docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

```sh
docker cp CONTAINER_ID:/20210910084030_psortb_gramneg.txt ./your/host/dir
```